# Setting up Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you go about setting up a Rails application on a standard web server? I want to just throw my application into cgi-bin and run it, but Rails clearly wants to control the file system and how file accesses are routed. So it's all very well working on my application in its little sandbox, but how do you actually close the gap and serve an application?

Comment: Deploying rails apps is a tad more complicated than, say, PHP. Deal with it. :) However, you can hide from that complexity. Take a look at Heroku, for example. Deploys are dead simple there.

Comment: to point you in the right direction, try looking at phusion passenger,https://www.phusionpassenger.com/ it works as the glue between rails and apache, or nginx, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Create Ruby on Rails app first then you can deploy it on Heroku. Here is very nice reference link from scratch..

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Hope this will help you..to create Rails Demo App and all steps of deploying on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

**Deploy**

There are a plethora of tutorials on how to deploy rails applications correctly.

Most notable (we've recently used) are:

> - [DigitalOcean - Deploying to a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu)
> - [GoRails - Deploying on Ubuntu with Nginx](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04)
> - [Heroku - Deploying to Heroku with GIT](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

This will give you information on how to deploy to either the Heroku *platform*, or one of the many VPS type hosting providers out there. We use Rackspace, and the DigitalOcean & GoRails tutorials were invaluable when setting up our server again

---

**Rails**

Although I'm not totally in tune with how Rails runs on file-system level, you have to appreciate that Rails runs with a multitude of dependencies & can also be compiled at run time

Processing requests in this way *has* to be handled by more than just the standard hosting software, and indeed, the most recommended solution from the [Rails core team](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy/) is [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/)